# What's wrong with my 875. Koko Eating Bananas LeetCode solution?

Tags: java, binary-search

The question is as follows -
Koko loves to eat bananas. There are n piles of bananas, the ith pile has piles[i] bananas. The guards have gone and will come back in h hours.

Koko can decide her bananas-per-hour eating speed of k. Each hour, she chooses some pile of bananas and eats k bananas from that pile. If the pile has less than k bananas, she eats all of them instead and will not eat any more bananas during this hour.

Koko likes to eat slowly but still wants to finish eating all the bananas before the guards return.

Return the minimum integer k such that she can eat all the bananas within h hours.

Example 1:

Input: piles = [3,6,7,11], h = 8
Output: 4

This is my solution for it-

```
class Solution {
    public int maxValueOf(int[] piles) {
        return Arrays.stream(piles).max().getAsInt();
    }

    public int canEatPiles(int capacityPerHour, int[] piles) {
        int sum = Arrays.stream(piles).sum();
        int hours = (int) Math.ceil((double) sum / capacityPerHour);
        return hours;
    }

    public int minEatingSpeed(int[] piles, int h) {
        int l = 1;
        int r = maxValueOf(piles);
        int mid = 0;

        while (l <= r) {
            mid = (l + r) / 2;
            if (canEatPiles(mid, piles) <= h) {
                r = mid - 1;
            } else {
                l = mid + 1;
            }
        }

        return mid;
    }
  
}
```

Could anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

The above code only passed 4/125 testcases, although it logically seems correct to me.

Comment: (i) first you need a case (data) that is not working; (ii) use a debugger to see what is going wrong